# Search and print result along with earlier information

Tags: python, awk, sed

I have total 30 test result files, each having 12 iterations in it. The structure of the file is as below:

**File1_loc/result.txt**

```
# starting information
# User information
# Time stamps
# Random infomration
# Thousnads of lines in between
# ----------------- Iteration 1 ----------------------
# $Test show addr 0x2341233  data 0x241341
# $Test matches Pass
# $Test show addr 0x123324  data 0x223245
# $Test matches Pass
# Few hundreds line
# $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=31ABCDEF Expected=21ABCDE
# ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 1
# $Test show addr 0x2341233  data 0x241341
# $Test matches Pass
# $Test show addr 0x123324  data 0x223245
# $Test matches Pass
# Few hundreds line
# ----------------------------------------------------
# ----------------- Iteration 2 ----------------------
# $Test show addr 0x2341233  data 0x241341
# $Test matches Pass
# $Test show addr 0x123324  data 0x223245
# $Test matches Pass
# Few hundreds line
# $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=31ABCDEF Expected=21ABCDE
# ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 2
# $Test show addr 0x2341233  data 0x241341
# $Test matches Pass
# $Test show addr 0x123324  data 0x223245
# $Test matches Pass
# Few hundreds line
# $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=EF12321 Expected=DL298234
# ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 3
# ----------------------------------------------------
This pattern continues
# ----------------- Iteration 12 ----------------------
# $Test show addr 0x2341233  data 0x241341
# $Test matches Pass
# $Test show addr 0x123324  data 0x223245
# $Test matches Pass
# Few hundreds line
# $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=31ABCDEF Expected=21ABCDE
# ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 4
# $Test show addr 0x2341233  data 0x241341
# $Test matches Pass
# $Test show addr 0x123324  data 0x223245
# $Test matches Pass
# Few hundreds line
# ----------------------------------------------------
```

I do have total 30 files like this. The file contains results and ERROR, if mismatch. I am interested to print the following information for each result.txt file.

```
    File1_Summary:
    # ----------------- Iteration 1 ----------------------
    # $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=31ABCDEF Expected=21ABCDE
    # ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 1
    # ----------------- Iteration 2 ----------------------
    # $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=31ABCDEF Expected=21ABCDE
    # ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 2
    # $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=EF12321 Expected=DL298234
    # ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 3
    # ----------------- Iteration 12 ----------------------
    # $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=31ABCDEF Expected=21ABCDE
    # ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 4
    File2_Summary:
    # ----------------- Iteration 1 ----------------------
    # $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=31ABCDEF Expected=21ABCDE
    # ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 1
    # ----------------- Iteration 12 ----------------------
    # $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=31ABCDEF Expected=21ABCDE
    # ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 2
```

I have used awk and search for the 4th field matching ERROR, which prints out the lines. However, I would like to also print out the Iteration # information.

```
awk '$4 ~/ERROR/' File1_loc/result.txt
```

Comment: `grep -E 'Iteration|ERROR' file`?

Comment: Do you want ALL Iteration lines printed or only those for blocks that contain an ERROR?

Comment: This looks like a quite simple `awk` programming question. Did you try to read the `awk` manual? You could simply store the `Iteration` lines in a variable (say `v`), the `$Test time: ERROR` lines in another (`u`) and, when encountering a `CHANGE ERROR COUNT` line, print `v`, `u` and the current line. What difficulties do you have with this, exactly?

Comment: do all iteration blocks contain at least one ERROR? if it's possible for an iteratoin block to have no ERRORs then please update the question with a sample iteration block with no ERROR, making sure to update the expected result (eg, do we print the iteration header? do we ignore the iteration and print nothing? something else?)

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions/understandings:

- print all lines that contain the string `Iteration` or `ERROR`

A couple variations on the same approach:

```
awk '$0 ~ /ERROR| Iteration /' result.txt

awk '/ERROR/ || / Iteration /' result.txt
```

Both of these generate:

```
# ----------------- Iteration 1 ----------------------
# $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=31ABCDEF Expected=21ABCDE
# ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 1
# ----------------- Iteration 2 ----------------------
# $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=31ABCDEF Expected=21ABCDE
# ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 2
# $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=EF12321 Expected=DL298234
# ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 3
# ----------------- Iteration 12 ----------------------
# $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=31ABCDEF Expected=21ABCDE
# ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 4
```

**NOTE:** this will always print the `Iteration` header/line regardless of whether or not the block contains an `ERROR`

---

---

If an `Iteration` header is only printed when the block contains an `ERROR` entry ...

Setup:

```
# edit the file and remove the 2x 'ERROR' lines from the 'Iteration 12' block
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
/ Iteration / { header=$0 }
/ERROR/       { if (header) {
                    print header
                    header=""
                }
                print
              }'
result.txt

# or as a one-liner:

awk '/ Iteration / { header=$0 } /ERROR/ { if (header) { print header; header="" } print }' result.txt
```

This generates:

```
# ----------------- Iteration 1 ----------------------
# $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=31ABCDEF Expected=21ABCDE
# ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 1
# ----------------- Iteration 2 ----------------------
# $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=31ABCDEF Expected=21ABCDE
# ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 2
# $Test time: ERROR: Results_dont_Match Loc: Actual=EF12321 Expected=DL298234
# ******:time ns: CHANGE ERROR COUNT TO: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and parallel):

```
parallel "sed '/^# --*/{:a;x;/ERROR/p;x;h;d};/ERROR/H;$!d;ba' file{}_loc/result.txt >file{}_summary.txt" ::: {1..30}
```

Return the iteration header and any lines within that iteration containing the word `ERROR` and place those lines in a summary file.

The input file directory and output summary file are indicated by the digit 1 to 30.